# Rails : Capistrano. Permisssion Denied(public key)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've been looking at a way to deploy my app using capistrano. I currently am hosting a small private repo on github and a local server to try deploying my test. I come upon a problem and an error message below.

I have done the following

1. Generate an ssh key on server and added it sucessfully to deploy keys in repo and tested(git@github.com)
2. Generate an ssh key on client and add it sucessfully to deploy keys in repo
3. setup a private repository. And have account deployer with rights to deploy
4. configed deploy.rb and production rb to follow mimic many other templates out there.

I still cannnot figure why it is giving me an error like this

```
    DEBUG [a5554d3d] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/App/git-ssh.sh
    INFO [a5554d3d] Finished in 0.020 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
    INFO [b1517df1] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:aceofw
    ings/App.git as deploy@192.168.1.84
    DEBUG [b1517df1] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/App/git-ssh
    .sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:aceofwings/App.git )

    DEBUG [b1517df1]        Permission denied (publickey).
    DEBUG [b1517df1]        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    DEBUG [b1517df1]
    DEBUG [b1517df1]        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    DEBUG [b1517df1]        and the repository exists.
    (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
    cap aborted!
    SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@192.168.1.84:
    git exit status: 128
    git stdout: Nothing written
    git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.

    SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
    git stdout: Nothing written
```

The Deploy.rb file

```
   ###############Deploy.rb##################
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:aceofwings/App.git'
set :application, 'App'
set :user, 'deploy'
#set :pty, true
# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp



# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')


namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

Production.rb

```
server '192.168.1.84', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}

#set :stage, :production
 role :app, %w{deploy@192.168.1.84}
 role :web, %w{deploy@192.168.1.84}
 role :db,  %w{deploy@192.168.1.84}


  set :ssh_options, {
    forward_agent: false,
    auth_methods: %w(password),
    password: 'Deploy4Real',
    user: 'deploy'
  }
```

Comment: so you can do `ssh -T git@github.com` when logged in to the `deploy` user ?

Comment: Yes I can, I can also do the same command on my local machine. Comes back with success

Comment: what about  `git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:aceofwings/App.git` on the `deploy` user on the server.

Comment: That did go through too.Very weird that this is happening

Comment: It's wierd that this command has another repository referenced: `INFO [b1517df1] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:aceofw
    ings/RotairApp.git`. was the app renamed to App from RotairApp or something ?

Comment: Its just App now, use to be RotairApp. Sorry for confusing you. Would the best course of action, try looking into the server perhaps. Or redoing this entire process?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It turns out that the SSH agent was not running. I found this out looking at the Capistrano documentation: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/

Running this command:

> $ ssh-add -l

showed me that my public key was not added to the agent so I had to add it:

> $ ssh-add

Identity added: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa)

After this my Capistrano deployment worked.

Answer (score 3):

You should set in production.rb:

```
forward_agent: true
```

I was having the same problem with Capistrano 3.4. With Capistrano 3.2.1 it seemed to ignore this parameter.

You can use [capistrano-ssh-doctor](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor) to troubleshoot possible config problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think your capistrano may have some old files in its git cache, probably from renaming the repository or something like that. Try to [delete](https://kovshenin.com/2011/capistrano-remove-cached-copy/) the `cached-copy` folder in the `shared` folder on the server, so capistrano will pull your repo again.